# CSV to bytes to DF to bypass UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode, byte

I have a csv which I have previously read to a dataframe without issue, but now is giving me the following error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'\\blah\blah2\csv.csv')
```

I tried this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'\\blah\blah2\csv.csv', encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```

but that gave me this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8-sig' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 10423: invalid start byte

So then I tried 'utf-16', but that gave me this error: UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM

Then I tried this:

```
with open(r'\\blah\blah2\csv.csv', 'rb') as f:
contents = f.read()
```

and that worked, but I need that csv as a dataframe, so then I tried:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame.to_string(contents)
```

but I got this error: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'columns'

Could someone please help me get my dataframe?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

This fixed it. It read the csv into a dataframe without the unicode errors.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'\\blah\blah2\csv.csv', encoding='latin1')
```

Comment: Without seeing the raw data, difficult to guess the encoding.  From your `'rb'` opening, update your question to report what `print(contents[:100])` displays.

Comment: Hello. The results of print(contents[:100]) are roughly this:b'longitude,produce,open,last_entitle,one,more_strings,etc,'

Comment: That doesn’t match your error since it doesn’t have an 0xff byte in position 0. Also note `latin1` will decode anything because it maps every byte to a Unicode code point, but not necessarily the correct code point.

Comment: That is the output, starting with b', and that is the error. Do you mean that latin1 will have random str characters throughout the output? That's not good. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Other than use the correct encoding, no. You haven’t shown a part of the string that is giving the errors reported. That would help to guess the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it. It read the csv into a dataframe without the unicode errors.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'\\blah\blah2\csv.csv', encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to find correct encoding with the code below:

```
# import the chardet library
import chardet 

# use the detect method to find the encoding
# 'rb' means read in the file as binary
with open(your_file, 'rb') as file:
    print(chardet.detect(file.read()))
```

However it is not guaranteed to find the encoding since the context may contain different encodings or different languages but, if it is encoded by only 1 code then you can see that.

```
pip(3) install chardet
```

if you dont have it installed

EDIT1:
Following is another way to find the right encoding. May this help if the above didn't:

```
from encodings.aliases import aliases
alias_values = set(aliases.values())

for value in alias_values:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(your_file, encoding=value) # or pd.read_excel
        print(value)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The first set of code did not work but the second produced this:cp858
iso8859_16
cp865
mac_iceland
cp850
cp1254
mac_roman
cp852
mac_turkish
cp855
cp1250
koi8_r
cp1257
cp1256
cp037
utf_16_be
cp869
cp860
cp1252
mac_greek  I don't know what to make of this. Do you know what I should do now? Thank you.